# Proxies not reconnecting to my SyncManager subclass automatically on server restart

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

If I kill the process that I called serve_forever from, and restart it, the clients don't reconnect. They don't reconnect automatically.  When I try deleting the manager client object "del obj" and creating a new one, I still get a BrokenPipeError each time I try to call the manager using the proxy or newly recreated proxy.

Manager:

```
import multiprocessing.managers, os, sys, time

class TestClass(object):
    def test_method(self):
        print("In test_method")
        return "TEST"

class TestManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass

address = ("127.0.0.1", 54321)
TestManager.register("Test", TestClass)
manager = TestManager(address = address, authkey = "1234".encode("utf-8"))
manager.get_server().serve_forever()
```

Client:

```
import multiprocessing.managers, os, sys, time

class TestManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass

address = ("127.0.0.1", 54321)
TestManager.register("Test")
manager = TestManager(address = address, authkey = "1234".encode("utf-8"))
manager.connect()
test_class = manager.Test()

def call_it():
    time.sleep(1)
    result = test_class.test_method()
    print("result: '" + str(type(result)) + ", " + str(result) + "'")

call_it()

print("Kill and restart the server and press return")
sys.stdin.readline()

error = False
while (True):
    try:
        if (error):
            print("Reconnecting")
            manager.connect()
            test_class = manager.Test()
        call_it()
        error = False
    except Exception as e:
        print("Got exception " + str(type(e)) + ", " + repr(e))
        error = True
time.sleep(1)
```

Note I have also tried adding the below before calling connect() again.

```
    del manager
    manager = TestManager(address = address, authkey = "1234".encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you are trying to execute? It will help us point out the issues.

Comment: I have updated the question with a code example.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? ive tried so many things with no luck

Comment: I didn't find a solution.  I finally had to switch to using a different form of RMI.  I am now using Pyro5.